# Insertar Datos en dos Tablas al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Intento ejecutar una función `mysqli_multi_query` pero solo me inserta los datos en una sola tabla (`docacu`) y la otra queda vacía. El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
 include 'conexion-agenda.php';

 $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

 if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion no pudo iniciarse: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$etareo = $_POST['select_etareo'];   
$modulo = $_POST['select_modulo'];
$turno = $_POST['select_turno']; 
$cons = $_POST['select_consultorio'];  
$deriv = $_POST['derivado_por'];
$acept = $_POST['acepta_doc'];

 $insert = "INSERT INTO agenda_pacientes (select_etareo, select_modulo, select_turno, select_consultorio, derivado_por, acepta_doc)
           VALUES ('$etareo', '$modulo', '$turno', '$cons', '$deriv', '$acept')";


  $insert = "INSERT INTO docacu (select_etareo, select_modulo, select_turno, acepta_doc)
    VALUES ('$etareo', '$modulo', '$turno', '$acept')"; 

   if (mysqli_multi_query($conexion,$insert) === TRUE)
 {

 // header('Location: http://localhost/agenda.php');
 echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "¡Atención!:" . "</h2>";
 echo "<h1>" . "El paciente ha sido agendado con éxito" . "</h1>";
 echo "<h1>" . "Derive al " . $_POST['select_modulo'] . "</h1>" . "\n\n";
 echo "<h4>" . "Siga las siguientes instrucciones: Mencione el nombre de la enfermera. Evite mencionarle al paciente el tiempo de espera. Indique al paciente que lo llamaran por su nombre." . "</h4>";
 echo "<h3>" . "Regresar a la Agenda " ."<a class= 'btn btn-info' href='agenda.php'>Regresar</a>" . "</h3>"; 
 }

 else {
 echo "Error al intentar agendar al paciente, intente de nueva cuenta" . $insert . "<br>" . $conexion->error; 
   }

 mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas sobreescribiendo la query, con un `.=` estaría solucionado.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO agenda_pacientes (select_etareo, select_modulo, select_turno, select_consultorio, derivado_por, acepta_doc) VALUES ('$etareo', '$modulo', '$turno', '$cons', '$deriv', '$acept');";


$insert .= "INSERT INTO docacu (select_etareo, select_modulo, select_turno, acepta_doc) VALUES ('$etareo', '$modulo', '$turno', '$acept');";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente. Pero tengo otra duda, tendría utilizar .= si quiero agregar mas funciones INSERT en el mismo código?

Comment: Si, o simplemente escribes todo seguido, pero siempre separando las querys por `;`.